# Import user defined package in java from outside of the subfolder

Tags: java, package

I have created a package in c:\world and I want to import it to my java source file stored in d:\java. It says that unable to access the package c:\world\Balance.class. What do i need to do??

Comment: `c:\world\Balance.class.` is not a package.. what is the name of your package?? And have you added the path till your package directory to your classpath??

Comment: does _Balance.class_ belong to a package? Are there any _package_ statements in the source for `Balance`?

Comment: i have added classpath c:\world and i am importing the package by writing import world.*

will it not work?

Comment: yes balance is a package... i added the line
package world;

Comment: @KunalGaurav.. Add class path till `C:\`.. You should not include your package directory in classpath..

Comment: I've assumed that you're compiling from the command line using `javac`. Are you doing that or using an IDE?

Comment: yes I am using command line javac

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to have the location of the imported classes on your classpath when compiling your classes and running your code.

From your description and comment, it sounds like you have a package named `world` with a class named `Balance`, with `Balance.class` in *c:\world*. This should work from *d:\java*:

```
javac -cp %CLASSPATH%;c:\ SomeClass.java
```

Replace `SomeClass.java` with the name (one or more) of the classes that you're trying to compile in *d:\java*.

You'll also need to have *c:\* in the classpath when you run your code.

Answer (score 0):

If you are seeing what I think you are seeing (no `c:\world` in the specific error message), then it's easy. You need to add `c:\world` to your CLASSPATH setting.

After that, a simple `import Balance` (or whatever) should suffice.

Otherwise, a MWE (Minimal Working Example) illustrating the issue, and **the exact error message** you are getting, would be helpful.

Comment: it says c:\world\Balance.class cannot be accessed

bad class name
Make sure that it is in the proper subfolder

Answer (score -1):

You have 2 ways to solve this problem:

1. Make the packages available in a single project, this means, both packages would be in the same source directory.
2. Make a jar that contains your `world` package. Copy this jar to your lib folder in your project and add it to the classpath, now the `world.Balance` class can be reached in your current project.